Query child changes in Gerrit
I wonder why there is not childof dual to the parentof query command in Gerrit in order to get all child changes ("the relation chain") from a change. Is there a way to query this (using the REST api)?
Documentation: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html
